# Java ignore a specific symbol after another specific symbol

Tags: java, csv

I have a .csv file. Data is divided by commas and I need to extract information out this file. Thing is if i just write this it works but partially:

```
    String file = "FinalProject/src/Data.csv";
    BufferedReader rd = null;
    String line = "";
    HashSet<String> platforms = new HashSet<String>();

    try
    {
        rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        rd.readLine();
        while ((line = rd.readLine())!=null)
        {
            String [] arr = line.split("\"");
            var words = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int i =0; i < arr.length;i++)
            {
                if(i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    words.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr[i].split(",")));
                }
                else
                {
                    words.add(arr[i]);
                }
                platforms.add(words.get(2));

             
            }


        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("");
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            rd.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {

            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

When I check the contents of Set and extract the same data out of the database created from this .csv file it shows difference. For example - my set has 38 values, when the database has 40, all of them are unique( nothing is repeated). I think the problem is caused by separation of data in .csv file with comma signs. Because some of these signs are inside of quotes and this probably causes a loss of the potential values that i need. Is there any solution to that problem? Or perhaps there is a more efficient way to deal with the comma sings inside of the quotes so that they are ignored?

Comment: Is there any reason you're basically writing a CSV parser yourself rather than using one of the many CSV parser libraries which already handle quoting in a robust and fully-tested way?

Comment: (As an aside, swallowing exceptions like that without even logging them almost always makes all kinds of things harder...)

Comment: you should use https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Comment: `System.out.println("");` - replace with the actual exception

Comment: Well, thing is this is sort of a task - I can not use any other specific tools to parse .csv file or to make a database out of it. Its like forbidden for 100%. I can only use Java to parse a .csv file and then again I have to use Java to create a SQL lite database. 
By the way don't look at the excetions, I'll update the code anyway, for now I just need to understand how to parse the .csv file correctly.

Comment: *I can not use any other specific tools to parse .csv file* Then you should probably start looking at the source code of tools that parse CSV properly and implement it yourself. Good luck!